# How to export phpunit coverage to xml ( necessary for jenkins reports )

Tags: jenkins, phpunit

I'm using phpunit and jenkins, the key is that jenkins creates report by using xml files with the results of tests, but I don't know how to export to an xml in phpunit, for now I saw only the option to export in HTML (for coverage).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This project](http://jenkins-php.org/) from Sebastian Bergmann should give you some pointers. It mentions the following config for PHPUnit...

```
<logging>
 <log type="coverage-html" target="build/coverage" title="Name of Project"
      charset="UTF-8" yui="true" highlight="true"
      lowUpperBound="35" highLowerBound="70"/>
 <log type="coverage-clover" target="build/logs/clover.xml"/>
 <log type="junit" target="build/logs/junit.xml"
      logIncompleteSkipped="false"/>
</logging>
```

... so I think you should try `--coverage-clover` instead of `--coverage-html` to get an XML-file.